# Display product dimensions (width, height, length) separately for variable product

Tags: woocommerce

In woocommerce I use "[Display woocommerce product dimensions in separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317041/display-woocommerce-product-dimensions-in-separate-lines/46318595#46318595)" answer code to display width, height and length separately in product page on `product-attributes.php` template file.

But the problem is that it doesn't display separated dimensions on variable products. When variation changes, it need to change the dimensions.

I need code that show this parameters for simple products and the variations of a variable product.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: To make it work for variable products (and its product variations) is something very complicated, a real development, so something too broad.

Comment: can you suggest me an alternative with a plugin for example? or it can be done with attributes?